# AngularJS datefilter with $watchGroup

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I needed some datestamp formatting for my Angular UI-Calendar, in the case 2 instances of calender. To catch the date change i was using watchGroup, since the two calendars need same type of formatting. In the end I could not do the same as with two separated $watch for each calender:

```
        $scope.$watchGroup(['dt_start', 'dt_end'], function(mydate) {

        newdate = $filter('date')(mydate, "dd/MM/yyyy");
        console.log(newdate);
    });
```

output: *[Fri Jan 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time), ...]*

with separated $watch's:

```
 $scope.$watch('dt_start', function(mydate) {
        newdate = $filter('date')(mydate, "dd/MM/yyyy");
        console.log(newdate);
    });

    $scope.$watch('dt_end', function(mydate) {
        newdate = $filter('date')(mydate, "dd/MM/yyyy");
        console.log(newdate);
    });
```

and I get a dd/MM/yyyy. Am I doing something wrong on the watchgroup expression?

Comment: `console.log(mydate)` its an array mostly, just check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$watchGroup takes two arrays and scope as parameters

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['dt_start', 'dt_end'], function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
    if (newValues[0] !== undefined) {
        var newStartDate = $filter('date')(newValues[0], "dd/MM/yyyy");
        console.log(newStartDate);
    }

    if (newValues[1] !== undefined) {
        var newEndDate = $filter('date')(newValues[1], "dd/MM/yyyy");
        console.log(newEndDate);
    }
});
```

You should check for any `undefined` values.

[AngularJS API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Comment: thanks man, the missing part was the newValues array as parameter.